# Make step when testing

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0, specs2

I am using IntelliJ 13 with Scala Play 2.
While the continuous compilation works great the make step when testing with Specs2 is terrible slow ( > 1 minute). Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to remove the Make step from run/debug configurations of Idea, Play compiler's job is to build on the fly, so it seems to be some kind of redundant.

Comment: Yes - but as far as I can see the test code is not compiled then / it doesn't pick up changes.